# Card.io get creditcard image and CardType key android

Tags: java, android, card.io

I m using card.io for scanning credit card in my app. My problem is i can not get card image logo (even i m passing (CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO, true)). as well i m not getting key for card(for example. VISA have 4,MASTERCARD have 55 or 51).

answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

what i mean for Key is CardTypeId. 
we are getting CardTypeId in ios like this..

```
(void)userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:(CardIOCreditCardInfo *)info inPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController *)scanViewController {
// The full card number is available as info.cardNumber, but don't log that!
NSLog(@"Received card info. Number: %@, expiry: %02i/%i, cvv: %@.cardtype %u", info.cardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv,info.cardType);
//getting cardtype (like visa) from info.cardType (this is what we called as CardTypeId //an ineger value)

NSString *cardTypeString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[CardIOCreditCardInfo     displayStringForCardType:info.cardType usingLanguageOrLocale:[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]]];
}
```

so how to get that integer number in android (info.cardType)
(info is object of CardIOCreditCardInfo)
FYI info.cardType returns integer like 53,52 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeff from card.io here.

We now allow the card type image to be retrieved in version 3.1.3 of the [card.io Android SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK).  To retrieve the card type image, please use

```
cardType.imageBitmap(context)
```

CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO is used for displaying the card.io logo when scanning a card, and is unrelated to retrieving the image logo.

Regarding the cardTypeId, I'm assuming you want the cardType enum and string.  In Android, CreditCard.getCardType() returns the [CardType](http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardType.html) enum, such as CardType.VISA or CardType.AMEX.  If you want a localized name of the retrieved credit card, just call

```
cardType.getDisplayName(null) //optionally pass in the desired locale
```

The enum values are not something that should be important, because enums are meant to be consumed as enums.  They should never be an undefined value (the [iOS header file](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CardIO/CardIOCreditCardInfo.h) does not show 52 or 53 as possible values).  If you think there's a bug, please file in in the [card.io GitHub Android repo](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK).

Comment: Thanx for updating..can we retrieve cardType image using card number or card type (CreditCard.getCardType()) in this new sdk ?

Comment: Yep!  I updated my previous answer a while back with the card type image example code.

Comment: @JeffBrateman there is logo of PayPal on right top corner how to change it to card.io?? And is there any way to remove that logo permanently??

Comment: Yes, use `CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO` to toggle between card.io and PayPal logos. No, you cannot remove the logo at this time.

Comment: Hey Jeff! Is it possible to have the Card.IO logo instead of PayPal's logo in the confirmation screen?

Comment: Yes!  This is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in method 
    【onActivityResult】

```
resultStr += "Card Type: " +  scanResult.getCardType().getDisplayName(null) + "\n";
```